# How to work with animate JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating progress bar and i'm animating it to 80% . i want when it reaches 80% , it stays for 3 to 4 seconds and then animate to 0% .

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r6zj42u3/1/

My JS

```
var progessss = $('#progressBar');
var counterProgressBar = 1;

for(var x = 0; x <= 1; x++){

    if(counterProgressBar === 1)
    {
        progessss.animate({
            'width':'+=80%'
        },1000);

    }

    counterProgressBar++;
}
```

i was trying

```
var progessss = $('#progressBar');
var counterProgressBar = 1;

for(var x = 0; x <= 1; x++){

    if(counterProgressBar === 1)
    {
        progessss.animate({
            'width':'+=80%'
        },1000);

    }
    else
    {
        progessss.animate({
          'width':'0%'
        },1000);
    }

    counterProgressBar++;
}
```

Comment: it was not edited but @sergej edits it. and i accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` for this

```
setTimeout(function(){ progessss.animate({
    'width':'0%'
},1000); }, 4000);
```

[***Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/r6zj42u3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

how about this [one](https://jsfiddle.net/7tgm3b4n/)

```
var progessss = $('#progressBar');
progessss.animate({
    'width':'+=80%'
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    progessss.animate({
        'width':'0%'
    },1000);
},5000)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as Anoop Joshi's answer?

Comment: I think @Anoop Joshi should get the 'accept' because it is the same answer and he was first...

Comment: Yes. I can remove this if required :)